# Determine when canvas content is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to detect when canvas content is loaded? What I'm trying is following. I need to print a page where in a widget is rendered a pdf document using the pdfjs library. Only the first pdf page have to be printed alongside with the content of the web page where the widget is placed. My approach was to get the canvas of the first pdf page which the pdfjs library created and put its content as source of an img element.

```
var content = canvas.toDataURL(); 
var img = document.createElement('img'); 
img.setAttribute('src', content); 
widget.parentNode.insertBefore(img, widget);
```

Now if I use this as is, the image is created but is blank. If I put the code above inside setTimeout with a few seconds delay the image is rendered properly with the content of the first pdf page but this is not reliable for me. I've checked the content returned by canvas.toDataURL() in both cases and it appeared not equal so this was the reason for my conclusion that the content of the canvas was not loaded yet.
Any ideas for solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does this `getContentURL()` method comes from? What library are you using? The default one would be `toDataURL()`

Comment: Thanks for catching. Fixed in the question.

Answer (score -1):

*canvas will bind to the DOM like any other html tag.* But your problem is image is not loading at very first time. So use `onload` method for loading images.

Refer [HTML5 Canvas Load Image Data URL](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-load-image-data-url/)

**EDIT :**
*drawImage() method draws an image or video onto the canvas.* So use that method to draw the image on canvas.

Here is the updated code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(this, 10, 10);   // here this = image, 10 = width of the image, 10 = height of the image
};

imageObj.src = dataURL;
```

For more information [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283698/image-not-loading-on-canvas)

Comment: Actually I've thought about this might be the image loading problem and tried the same thing you've suggested, but the onload handler fired immediately and the image left blank.

Comment: Have you tried to set the width and height of the image, after it was loaded.?

Comment: I appreciate your advice but I think you've get the question wrong. I don't want to draw a canvas but to get the content of a canvas which is already on the page and to load/output that content as an image.

Comment: > Have you tried to set the width and height of the image, after it was loaded.? 

Yes. I've size applied to the image. I tried both: set it like inline css and as image attributes width and height. I have to say that this didn't help either. Although the image size is my other problem. The image (when it appears) has much lower resolution than it has in the canvas.

Comment: This answer, in no way addresses OPS question.