# simple J.S. mistake (without error log as it should be)

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone and thanks for trying to help me ..

I'm trying to create a tiny car game in javaScript, but i actually can't print an image ...
Here's my JS code :

```
// Parametters 
const canvasWidth = 500;
const canvasHeight = 500;

const carLength = 60;
const carWidth = 30;

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = canvasWidth;
canvas.height = canvasHeight;
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

drawAll();

function drawAll() {
    console.log('draw canvas background');
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    drawCar();
}

function drawCar() {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = 'assets/images/car_orange.png';
    context.drawImage(image, 200, 200, carLength, carWidth);
}
```

and here's the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/pageIcon/pageIcon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 
    <title>CrossingCars</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="drinving_environment.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the mistake is that my code don't print the image as drawCar() function should do, but if I type each line of code separately in my console it works ...

[before console use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEs9D.png)

[after console use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs9ve.png)

Comment: What happens if you `setTimeout(drawAll, 1000);` instead of calling `drawAll` directly, allowing time for the elements to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your image content isn't loaded yet. You should wait until your image is loaded.

Please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283698/image-not-loading-on-canvas)
This issue is always happening on canvas.

```
    ...
    function drawCar() {
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = 'assets/images/car_orange.png';
        image.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(image, 200, 200, carLength, carWidth);
        }
    }
    ...
```